# Invoke rest API having dynamic query params

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, dynamic

I am working on a project where I have to "GET" rest API using java. There are approx. 20 query parameters in rest API which make each call unique.

API URL 1: http://mock.domain.com/api?param1=value
API URL 2: http://mock.domain.com/api?param2=value
API URL 3: http://mock.domain.com/api?param3=value&param4=value
API URL 4: http://mock.domain.com/api?param5=value&param4=value

All these API's has the same URI but query params make them unique. I have to create a wrapper on these API's such that API endpoint is invoked only when input validation is correct.

One approach is to create 
1. POJO class to set all input params and do basic validation using spring boot
2. Before invoking endpoint create if, else statements and validate all input validations. For eg; If param3 is set then param4 should be set as well and so on.

But I am myself not convinced with this approach, this would be too wordy and tedious to manage. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. The API design sounds wonky to begin with, but you can "fix" this on the java side by writing one method for each valid combination of parameters and giving it a proper name, e.g. `getByName(String param1)` and `getBySurnameAndAge(String param3, int param4)`.

Comment: I agree that API design is wonky but I do not have control on that and have to deal with this design only. I have the similar solution in mind but want to know are there any better options available to handle this situation?